# How Can I Create Membership Tables In My Own Database in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have used `aspnet_regsql` in visual studio 2010 command prompt that would open the membership wizard to create tables and stored procedures for me at my own database.
Now, these tables usually use `'aspnet_'` prefix. 
However, in visual studio 2012 default website template, I saw that these tables don't have the prefix i-e `'aspnet_'` associate to their name. 
**How, can I create those tables and specify my custom database.** Just like in visual studio 2010 command prompt. 
**How can I call that utility in visual studio 2012?**

Comment: Why can't you could simply change them by hand.  It would take less then 5 minutes to export the current table, edit the text file by hand, and import the table.

Answer (score 0):

You select good version of framework, before run tools

Here on msdn they don't speak about change.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89hwy0w9

Comment: There any way we can use proper english in answers.  Furthermore using .NET Framework 4.5 at this point is perfectly acceptable.